# How to update image on customizable option change

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-options

In my site I need to change product's main image on customizable option change.

I have a text field customizable option. When it updates, I make a call to some URL and that URL returns me an image.

I need to set this image as main image for the current product, just for preview. I don't need to save the image in  Magento. I just need to get the image as main image by adding it before other images of the product.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this, just check for change on the text field and update the main image with the image you get.

```
require(['jQuery'], function($){
    $('#textFiledId').on('change', function(){
        let src = 'img.jpg'; // get image using ajax 
        //set src to main image 
    });
}
```